# Ext Js 5 Customized button -activeCls not working

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Hi I have added the below poperties to my ExtJs 5 button class ,

```
 overCls :'addbutton-over',
 pressedCls :'addbutton-pressed',
 activeCls:'addbutton-active',
```

Mouse over and pressed are working , but  button active it load default extjs active style, please help me to add extjs button active style

Answer (score 0):

script extjs above is right, but i don't know the other. like how you definition the class on the css file, or other selector may be overwrite so the style didn't show like exactly you want.

Please check again and show us the other code so we can analyze it more.